# How can I OOM kill a pod manually in Kubernetes

Tags: linux, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, infrastructure, sre

I'm trying to manually OOM Kill pods for testing purposes, does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: can you lower their memory limit until they oom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run [stress-ng](https://github.com/ColinIanKing/stress-ng) in the pod. With this tool you can also stress CPU, I/O altogether if you need.